# Using a Controller and Restcontroller to allow users to access any page

Tags: spring

I am using Spring Framework to build a webapp. I have a restcontroller that verifies the user (Google oAuth) and sends responses to the page to determine if the user is valid. There is another page on the site, however, called storage. If the user wanted to go straight to mysite.com/storage. How would I send the user to that page? I tried having a regular controller to direct the user there but I get a circular path error. What is the right practice here? Am I missing anything? Thanks. let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Is that page (mysite.com/storage) a server side served? Or a standalone javascript web application?

Comment: Its a server side served. As of now my workaround is visiting localhost:8080/storage.html and letting the server send the html file, instead of a controller handling it. Then the storage.html has a JS on it that communicates to my Rest Controller that verifies the user, which eventually returns an http response to that storage page.